# Четкий поиск по постам VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Как реализовать "строгий/четкий" поиск постов в вк?

Есть api "newsfeed.search" (https://vk.com/dev/newsfeed.search)

При передачи параметра `q` например `Купить машину`

Вк делает поиск отдельно `Купить` и `машину`

Нужно, чтобы он делал поиск именно по фразе `Купить машину`, чтобы эта фраза была в посте

Comment: Насколько мне известно такое невозможно, но можно попробовать брать все результаты и дальше уже проверять (отсортировать/фильтрация), к примеру, регулярным выражением на строгое соответствие.

Answer (score 1):

Оберните запрос в двойные кавычки.